What's the difference between Building and Design?
We have a couple of tags on the main site that are semantically similar, but are generally being used in different ways:

building
design

At the moment, questions tagged "Building" are all about building techniques, "how do I build..." type questions, while questions tagged "Design" are generally used on questions about set/element design which I think is correct.
However some questions that are more about building a particular model have been tagged "design" as in "How do I design a mechanism to do this".
Should we make design a synonym of building?
Should we keep them separate and update the wiki on design to be more explicit about the use of this, state that if your question is about a MOC it should be tagged building?

I originaly thought building was more to do with the process of building with LEGO but it seems to be more or less the same thing as design. 
It could also be assumed that building refers to an individual structure such as a house or a bank as opposed to the process of building.
We should give each tag a wiki summary if we plan on keeping them separate.

That's kind of what happened with the Building and Technique tags (http://meta.bricks.stackexchange.com/q/118/56) hence the tag summary that explicitly talks about "building techniques" on building.
